# How to create a UINavigationController that hovers onscreen (not translate the screen downward)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I would like to have a `UINavigationController` that hovers on the current screen instead of "translating" the screen downward to make way for it.

Currently my implementation goes like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

So that what happens is everytime I show the navigationItem, it slides itself downwards into the screen, translating the entire screen. And then when I hide it, it slides out, pulling back the entire screen up. I'd like it to hover instead, i.e. the position of the screen remains untouched. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per question, you want to animate screen when we push screen from navigation controller. I have done in my project. Steps as below

1) When you push view controller from Navigation Controller means, You have to animate current view controller when we push. code as below

```
 (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

2) If you want to pop from second view controller to first view controller means, you have type same code in second view controller.. You can change animation transition side by modify this method argument `setAnimationTransition`